# Using Dplyr inner_join to combine tables with partial matches

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join

Two data sets:

```
> head(all_USFWS_Ref)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -2070770 ymin: 1633702 xmax: 510000 ymax: 2880340
Projected CRS: NAD83 / Conus Albers
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  ORGNAME                                 ORGCODE SHAPE_Length SHAPE_Area                                                                 SHAPE
  <chr>                                     <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>                                                    <MULTIPOLYGON [m]>
1 ABERNATHY FISH TECHNOLOGY CENTER          13210        3553.    452673. (((-2070361 2879939, -2070360 2879939, -2070299 2879989, -2070293 28…
2 ADAMS COUNTY WATERFOWL PRODUCTION AREA    32525        5274.   1386307. (((510000 2334373, 508982.4 2334308, 508979.7 2334332, 508963.3 2334…
3 ADAMS COUNTY WATERFOWL PRODUCTION AREA    64530        7245.   1594547. (((-216126.9 1947014, -216941.4 1947011, -216912.8 1947837, -216111.…
4 AGASSIZ NATIONAL WILDLIFE REFUGE          32510       76511. 252006533. (((9541.592 2823031, 10356.2 2823015, 10355.74 2823029, 10357.1 2823…
5 AITKIN COUNTY WATERFOWL PRODUCTION AREA   32588        2408.    298171. (((208739.6 2620618, 208165.2 2620597, 208141.2 2621014, 208332.4 26…
6 ALAMOSA NATIONAL WILDLIFE REFUGE          65510       49412.  48874387. (((-861118.9 1647597, -861028.1 1647472, -861082 1647168, -860959.4 …
```

and

```
> head(Colorado)
     name VPU   ID refuge_code percent feature
1 Alamosa  13 1543         CO1  0.5742     HRU
2 Alamosa  13 1511         CO1  0.2965     HRU
3 Alamosa  13 1499         CO1  0.0847     HRU
4 Alamosa  13 1509         CO1  0.0175     HRU
5 Alamosa  13 1492         CO1  0.0151     HRU
6 Alamosa  13 1485         CO1  0.0065     HRU
```

Trying to combine the "name" Column in Colorado dataset which is the first word in the ORGNAME df to match with the partial "ORGNAME" in all_USFWS_Ref using the inner join to keep the polygons and remaining columns in all_USFWS_Ref.

When I use inner_join the table produces to matches and is blank.

```
state_df <- all_USFWS_Ref %>% 
  inner_join(Colorado, by = c("ORGNAME" = "name")))
```

I have tried to make it non case sensitive as well

```
state_df <- all_USFWS_Ref %>%
  mutate(ORGNAME = tolower(ORGNAME)) %>%
  inner_join(Colorado %>% mutate(name = tolower(Name)), by = c("ORGNAME" = "name"))
```